# How do I execute asynchronous functions in a synchronous loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web-scraping, async-await

I am (legally) scraping a website to migrate it to a WordPress backend using JavaScript and Node. To avoid timeouts I want to wait for a small period of time between every URL I'm scraping. I'm looping over all the URLs using forEach. The requests in these iterations are asynchronous, but using async/await that means I have to make my iterations async as well.

```js
const wait = (time) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
};

async function main() {
  urls.forEach(async (url, index) => {
    await wait(1000);
    console.log('Waiting');
    const scraper = new Scraper({ ...scraperOptions, url });
    const pageTitle = await scraper.getPageTitle();
    const pageContent = await scraper.getContentFromSelector(".page-content", "html");

    const post = await importer.createPost(pageTitle, pageContent, "specialisms");
    console.log(`Created new post with ID ${post.id}`);
  });
}

main();
```

Because of this, the `wait(1000)` function is starting at about the same time for every iteration, thus not adding time between iterations. The output would be something like:

```bash
> Waiting
> Waiting
> Waiting
>
> Created new post with ID 1
> Created new post with ID 2
> Created new post with ID 3
```

How do I approach this problem? Is there a way to bundle asynchronous operations and run the next iteration only if the current one is finished?

Comment: use a `for`, `for...of` or `for...in` loop - there's a question that explains it - still looking - edit: found it

Comment: I feel stupid for not finding that post myself, I did try some searches. Thank you @JaromandaX, much appreciated!